# Download from list of URLs and output to relative directories

Tags: bash, wget

I have a list of URLs in a text file:

```
http://host/index.html
http://host/js/test.js
http://host/js/sub/test_sub.js
http://host/css/test.css
```

I would like to download these files by replicating the same tree on my filesystem. For example, I would like to end with the following tree when I'm done:

```
wd/
 |_index.html
 |_js/
 |  |_test.js
 |  |_sub/
 |     |_test_sub.js/
 |_css/
    |_test.css
```

Here's what I've tried:

Add target file as second argument in list:

```
http://host/index.html 
http://host/js/test.js js/test.js
http://host/js/sub/test_sub.js js/sub/test_sub.js
http://host/css/test.css css/test.css
```

Use a while loop to tell `wget` where to save these:

```
 while read url target; do
   wget "$url" -P "$target";
 done < site_media_list.txt
```

This didn't work, the end result was all files in same directory, without new directories.

Answer (score 10):

Make a file with list of only links (no paths), one on each line, then `wget -nH -x -i links_list.txt` downloads files to working directory keeping the directory structure intact. A more readable version of the same command is given below.

```
wget --no-host-directories --force-directories --input-file=links_list.txt
```

Wget has many flexible options for directories. Look up [`man wget` directory options](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Directory-Options) for more.

Answer (score 1):

Split the path on `/` into an array, use only the relevant elements to create the path.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read url ; do
    IFS=/ parts=($url)
    if (( ${#parts[@]} > 4 )) ; then
        IFS=/ path="${parts[*]:3:${#parts[@]}-4}"
        mdkir -p "$path"
    fi
    IFS=/ wget -O "${parts[*]:3}" "$url"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file `site_media_list.txt` is containing only the files list (and not target directories), you should be able to parse out the directory names from the URL:

```
while read -r url ; do
  s=$(echo "$url" | sed -E 's#http://host/(.*/)?.*$#\1#')
  if [[ -z "$s" ]]; then
    echo "working dir"
    wget "$url"
  else
    echo "subdir"
    mkdir -p "$s"
    wget $url -P "$s"
  fi
done < site_media_list.txt
```

It looks like the main problem you were having is that you were passing the directory name *and* filename to `wget` - you only need to pass the directory name - `wget` will calculate the filename from the URL.